# Androidでタブとナビゲーションビューの併用

Tags: android

Androidアプリ開発初心者です。

タブの実装は出来たのですが、次にナビゲーションビューを設置しようとするとレイアウトが崩れたりと上手く併用が出来ません。
MainActivityに2つの要素を置くものではないのでしょうか。
頓珍漢な質問になっているかも知れませんが、良い方法をお教えください。
よろしくお願いします。

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<samples.exoguru.materialtabs.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: レイアウトXMLを貼り付けてください

Comment: 編集しました。
これで大丈夫でしょうか...？

Comment: 用語の確認です。ナビゲーションバーは「iOSだとNavigationBarに相当するもの」であっていますか？

Comment: 申し訳ないです...NavigationViewでした...

Answer (score 1):

`DrawerLayout`を使います。

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <samples.exoguru.materialtabs.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Drawer部分はここに -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```